# mysql: запись в базу данных несколько записей по одному запросу

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите, можно ли с помощью SQL выполнить запись в базу (insert) несколько записей для каждой найденной записи,

Например:

```
insert into table2 (filed1, field2) values (XXXXX, table1.id) where select id from table1 where value > 10
```

под `XXXXX` я хотел бы сделать 2 записи с разными значениями, но с одинаковым `table1`

т.е. как-то хотелось бы соединить записи

```
insert into table2 (filed1, field2) values (1, table1.id) where select id from table1 where value > 10

insert into table2 (filed1, field2) values (2, table1.id) where select id from table1 where value > 10
```

в один запрос

возможно ли это сделать?
если да, то можно ли усложнить и запись

```
insert into table2 (filed1, field2) values (2, table1.id) where select id from table1 where value > 10
```

выполнять только если выполняется условие для `table1` на наличие определённых записей (например, что такого id не встречалось и т.п.)

Понятно, что я все легко могу разбить на несколько запросов, но интересует именно возможность пополнения таблицы одним запросом, а не несколькими

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите тексты своих запросов в соответствие с SQL-синтаксисом. INSERT .. VALUES никакого WHERE в принципе не допускает. А то бред какой-то, а не запросы, хрен поймёшь, что они делают. И обязательно укажите точную версию MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так хочется?

```
insert into table2 (
  filed1,
  field2
) select
  1, id
from
  table1
where
  value > 10
union
select
  2, id
from
  table1
where
  value > 20
```

Comment: по идее решение хорошее, но опять же есть одно но - сначала будет вставлено 100 записей по первому запросу, потом 100 по второму, а хотелось бы 1 по первому 1 по второму 2 по первому 2 по второму и т.д.

Comment: @Zhihar а какая разница? это ни на что не влияет.

Comment: @Zhihar Любая СУБД хранит записи в произвольном порядке. Если вам нужно отображать их в определенном добавьте к запросу выборки `ORDER BY`